# Cannot import neo4j in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, neo4j, cypher

Neo4j driver v1.5.3 has been installed, Neo4j is running. After that I've tried to run example:

```
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase

uri = "bolt://localhost:7687"
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=("neo4j", "password"))

def print_friends_of(tx, name):
    for record in tx.run("MATCH (a:Person)-[:KNOWS]->(f) "
                         "WHERE a.name = {name} "
                         "RETURN f.name", name=name):
        print(record["f.name"])

with driver.session() as session:
    session.read_transaction(print_friends_of, "Alice")
```

But I'm getting:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/experiment/Cypher.py", line 1, in 
>       from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'neo4j'
>   Process finished with exit code 1

Additional info using: (venv) >pip freeze

> aiohttp==3.1.2 appdirs==1.4.3 async-timeout==2.0.1 attrs==17.4.0
>   beautifulsoup4==4.6.0 certifi==2018.1.18 chardet==3.0.4 idna==2.6
>   idna-ssl==1.0.1 lxml==4.2.1 multidict==4.1.0 neo4j-driver==1.5.3
>   packaging==17.1 py2neo==3.1.2 pyparsing==2.2.0 PyQt5==5.10.1
>   pyqt5-tools==5.9.0.1.2 python-dateutil==2.7.2 requests==2.18.4
>   selenium==3.11.0 sip==4.19.8 six==1.11.0 urllib3==1.22 yarl==1.1.1

So, what I do wrong?

UPDATE
I'm using PyCharm 2018.1.3 (pro) and python 3.6.1. All modules were installed using pip. The strange thing is that I just successfully ran this script directly using Windows PowerShell command string "python c:\experiment.cypher.py". So, the problem is in PyCharm, or I have something to do to make this work inside PyCharm?

Comment: And I assume you're running the python3 that's in your venv?   This error would be expected if you were running regular python3 that wasn't using your locally installed packages, right?    Maybe update question showing how you're running this.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits Thank you for your response. I'm using PyCharm 2018.1.3 (pro) and python 3.6.1. All modules were installed using pip. The strange thing is that I just successfully ran this script directly using Windows PowerShell command string "python c:\experiment.cypher.py". So, the problem is in PyCharm, of I have something to do to make this work inside PyCharm? PS Sorry for newbie question.